# background image property in css not working

Tags: css, html

I am trying to set background property in my file but the image is not loading

**html code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\css\recipe.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="div1a"></div>
      <div class="div1b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
   <div class="div3"></div>
   <div class="div4"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**css code:**

```
.div1b{
    border-style:solid;
    height:28em;
    width:71em;
    background: url('C:\Users\Lakha\Documents\My Web Sites\Food 
    website\img\banner.jpg');
```

}

I tried the following steps:

--> Checked the image is in the correct folder.
--> Tried using double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: do not use an absolute path like that. Do use a relative one instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is on your site, wich seems the case, you have to provide a relative url for it, not an absolute one, because your hard drive isn't accessible from internet (thank's god...). The url is formatted with / characters to separate folders, and no \ like in Windows.

So the url will be something like this:

```
url(img/banner.jpg)
```

assuming that the "Food website" folder is the root of your site and the css is directly in it.

Comment: i think the issue is not with absolute or relative path .. both should work fine but we need to pay attention to the syntax .. maybe you need to add this in you answer to be a complete one.

Comment: A path is not an url... An "absolute path" will NEVER work if you expose the site throug a web server, it will only work if you open the html file locally. Other thing would be if you're referring to an "absolute url" that could be "http://example.com/whatever/image.jpg" wich then it's fine.

Comment: i totally understand, and it's clear that he want to open the file locally, so he need first to understand that he's written the url wrong and then explain to him to better use relative than absolute. am not against what you are saying .

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your css file path in `href="correct css file path"`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/recipe.css">
```

you may got it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use an absolute path. Try using a location relative to the location of the css file. like this:

```
background: url('..\img\banner.jpg');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can insert an image into your web folder

```
.div1b{
    border-style:solid;
    height:28em;
    width:71em;
    background: url('../img/banner.jpg');

}
```